# How to get some specific lines from huge text file in unix?

Tags: unix

I use importing systems based on delimited text files. The files used can sometimes be almost 2 Gb big and I have to check some lines from that file.
   So I want to know how can I output (on another file, or just on screen) the lines of specific value? E.g. line number 1010123, 1002451, 994123, etc., exactly as they are in the source file?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To print line `N`, use:

```
sed 'Nq;d' file
```

To print multiple lines (assuming they are in ascending order) e.g. 994123, 1002451, 1010123:

```
sed '994123p;1002451p;1010123q;d' file
```

The `q` after the last line number tells `sed` to quit when it reaches the 1010123th line, instead of wasting time by looping over the remaining lines that we are not interested in. That is why it is efficient on large files.

Comment: in relation to that, a good link : https://webhostinghero.org/how-to-view-and-edit-large-files-in-linux/

Comment: "That is why it is efficient on large files" - unless you need a line toward the end of the file, in which case it's not very efficient anymore (I just tried on a 40GB file). Nevertheless, your answer is great, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with many Unix tools, for instance with `awk`:

```bsh
# print first 5 lines with awk
awk 'NR>=1&&NR<=5{print}NR>=6{exit}' file

# print selection of lines 
awk 'NR==994123||NR==1002451||NR==1010123{print}NR>1010123{exit}' file
```

Comment: How does `sed` / `awk` perform on very large files like those he mentioned in his question (~2GB)?

Comment: The line numbers are not sequential. Not first Nth or last Nth. They are just lines with errors. I have line numbers in a table and I just want to output just specific line numbers.

Comment: @BogdanM see the 2nd `awk` example for this (dogbane answers shows how with sed) I thought printing ranges would also be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
readThisFile = open('YOURFILE')
outputFile = open('OUTPUT', w)

for actualline, linetext in enumerate(readThisFile):
    if actualline == WANTEDLINE
        outputFile.write(linetext)
    else:
        pass
```

If wanted you can modify that script to work with arguments (like getline.py 1234)

Comment: It would more efficient to quit after `outputFile.write(linetext)` is printed also as the question is tagged only `unix` so I'm uncertain the OP has `Python` available.

Comment: I can't say if there's Python available on it or not (he didn't say which language he want's the solution written in).
And because of quitting at the line: Yeah that can be done, but my script isn't a "it's ready to use, just copy and paste it" script, it's just a hint how it can be done