# Extract large list of lines from large text file

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I need to extract ~5000 lines from a file with ~300,000 lines on bash (OSX). Running

```
sed '128082p;128083p;...(4996 numbers)....;159845q;d' file > output
```

gives the error

```
sed: 1: "128082p;128083p;128084p ...": command expected
```

This same command works if I try to extract 10 lines only. Whereas running

```
for i in `cat line_file`; do sed -n "$ip" file; done >> output
```

creates a file that's more than ~5000 lines long. What's the right command in either case?

Edit: this is not a range of numbers.

Comment: @Sundeep The list of numbers doesn't appear to be a range `128082 + 5000 = 133082` not the number that the user posted: `159845`.

Comment: @sorontar, true.. question is unclear.. but I think OP wants a range (whatever that might be)

Comment: why do you have the trailing `;d`? And what about `sed -n '128082,133082p;133083q' file > out` ? Good luck.

Comment: Also, I think the non-sequitur error msg is just the result of blowing out the MAX_LINE_SIZE value for the cmd-line. Using a range as I show above has been legal in sed since it was created. No need to enumerate each line num. individually. (Or am I completely misunderstanding your Q and problem? It wouldn't be the first time ;-) )  Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: I had the same thought re max. command line length (`getconf ARG_MAX`), but it turns out to be a much lower limit built into BSD `sed` itself: the input script is cut off at 2048 bytes... (and if the max. command-line length had been exceeded, the error message would have read `Argument list too long`).

Comment: @Sundeep I forgot to be explicit, this is not a range/interval of numbers.The rest of the examples on SO work on intervals or small lists of lines, or otherwise non-OSX environments.

Comment: @shellter I didn't mention but this is not a range/interval of lines. I suspected it was a size limit problem. I used the trailing ";d" from a suggestion in a question posted here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/14709384/4296422

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) for his help.</sup>

It looks like **BSD `sed`** as used on macOS (as of macOS 10.12.1) has a **hard limit on the size of each *line* of a script** that can be passed to it: **`2048` bytes**.

When passed as a *command-line argument* (implicitly as the first operand, or explicitly via `-e` options), scripts are typically passed as a *single* line, as you did.

If that single line gets too long, it is regrettably blindly cut off, typically resulting in a seemingly random syntax error, like the one you saw.

There are two **workarounds**:

- Make sure that your script contains only short-enough lines by separating commands with `\n` (newlines) instead of `;` and/or split your script across multiple `-e` options (which is cumbersome).
- Provide the entire script via a *file*, using the `-f` option, in which case all commands *must* be separated with `\n` rather than `;` anyway.
  In the unlikely event that your script is too long to fit on a single command line (a limit imposed by the *system* - see bottom), using `-f` is your only option.

---

Here's an example of a command-line script that is too long:

```
$ sed -n "$(printf '%sp;' {1..432})" <<<'line 1'
sed: 1: "1p;2p;3p;4p;5p;6p;7p;8p ...": command expected # !! ERROR
```

Even though the script is syntactically correct, cutting its one and only line off at 2048 bytes leaves it incorrect, resulting in the seemingly random `command expected` error.

In this case, working around the limitation is simple: by replacing `;` with `\n`, the individual lines become short enough:

```
$ sed -n "$(printf '%sp\n' {1..432})" <<<'line 1'
line 1 # OK
```

Since you already have a file of *line numbers* - `line_file` - you can use an *auxiliary* `sed` command to create your `\n`-separated script from it:

```
 $ sed -n "$(sed 's/$/p/' line_file)" file > output
```

---

Here's how to solve the problem via a script *file* passed via `-f`, in which the commands are `\n`-separated fixes the problem:

```
$ printf '%sp\n' {1..432} > script.sed # Create script file with \n-separated commands.
$ sed -n -f "script.sed" <<<'line 1' # Pass script file via -f
line 1 # OK
```

Note: Using a process substitution (`sed -n -f <(printf ...) ...`) as an ad-hoc script file inexplicably does *not* work.

Also note that the *overall* max. length of a command line for invoking an external utility such as `sed` on macOS (as of 10.12) is `262144` (256 KB; determined with `getconf ARG_MAX`), and in practice the limit is lower, because the size of the environment-variable block plays a role.
If you were to hit that limit, however, you'd get a more helpful error message: `Argument list too long`.

Comment: Your size limit is what I suspected but did not know about, since it worked on smaller commands. The "sed -n "$(sed 's/$/p/' line_file)" file > output" command worked, and in less than a minute. 1+ also for very helpful explanations.